# How to update subtotal price on updating quantity without 'Úpdate cart' click in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

We need to remove 'Update Cart' button to update subtotal value and want to calculate subtotal amount using `jQuery`.

```
<input type="hidden" class="item-unit-price" value="{{item.unitPrice}}"/>
```

And on click +/- or on manual quantity update calculate sub-total using `jQuery` method

`function update_price(object){
    current_quantity = $(object).parents('.quantity-input').find('input[type=number]').val();
    item_price = $(object).parents('.quantity-input').find('.item-sub-total').val();
    console.log(current_quantity);
    console.log(item_price);
    $(object).parents('.quantity-input').next('.cart-item-quantity').html("<span><b>"+ (current_quantity*item_price) +"</b></span>");
}`

But how we can find current channel Currency Symbol($)/decimal points(2 decimal) in twig?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`{% import "@SyliusShop/Common/Macro/money.html.twig" as money %}
{{ money.format(item.unitPrice, cart.currencyCode) }}`

instead of `{{item.unitPrice}}`